# Using H2 1.4 database can I write new rows if reading other rows

Tags: sql, concurrency, h2

Using H2 1.4 database can I write new rows if reading other rows?

i.e if have 1000 rows in table, and have a SELECT query running that is getting  primary key 1-10 would it be possible for an INSERT query to insert some new rows at same time, or would it have to wait for (all) the SELECT query on that table to finish?

What is the situation with an UPDATE of rows in table table but not being retrieved by any SELECT query?

I ask because with H2 1.3 I noticed that my application threads that accessed database seemed to spend a lot of time blocking, it seems better now I have upgraded to 1.4. But in my application that is multithreaded the threads are always dealing with different rows so it is important for me to better understanding how locking works in H2 (with the MV store, was previously using PAGE store with 1.3), and whether H2 can just lock individual rows when UPDATING or if it has to lock whole table.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on storage engine that you choose. All information below applies to the most recent version (1.4.199), old versions have some differences.

- With default MVStore engine data modification operations and `SELECT … FOR UPDATE` lock modified (or selected) rows. Other transactions can't modify locked rows in parallel, but can read their values. Note that read committed isolation level is used by default and other isolation levels are not really supported by this engine. With read committed isolation level other transactions will not see the concurrently modified values, they will see old ones. New values will be visible only when that transaction commits its work. With this engine database runs in multi-threaded mode by default, so a long-running command will not block other sessions.
- With legacy PageStore engine (add `;MV_STORE=FALSE` to the connection URL if you want to create a database with this engine) the whole tables are locked for writing. It means that you really need to lock the tables in the same order (alphabetical or some other) in all your transactions, otherwise a deadlock is possible. With this engine database runs in single-threaded mode by default, you can enable multi-threaded mode explicitly, but it is not safe with this engine. Different sessions can't do their work concurrently, long-running command will block all other sessions.

Databases are not converted from old (PageStore) format to a new (MVStore) format when you open them with a new version of H2, you have to do it by yourself. Also old databases may have serious problems with new versions, it's recommended to export them to SQL with old version of H2 using the `SCRIPT TO 'filename.sql'` command and load this script into new database with a new version of H2 using the `RUNSCRIPT FROM 'filename.sql'` command. You need to do it even if you choose to use the old engine. If you have persistent databases don't forget to create regular backup copies (with `BACKUP TO 'filename.zip'` command, for example).

You can find more details in the documentation:

https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc

https://h2database.com/html/features.html#multiple_connections